# Reading .reg files with python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, registry

I have a set of .reg files from a few machines that I would like to parse with python pandas.

if newline starts with [ it is the path for the below items

if the newline starts with a ", the item from the start of the new line to the equals sign is is the key with the path that is above it

If the line contains a : and is not a path, the item after the = sign and preceding the colon is considered the type.

if the there is no type, than the item after the equals sign is the value

if the type contains hex at all than the lines following it need to be added to the full key valuewithout the backslashes basically having the hex all on one line in the dataframe.

Dataset looks as follows with much more in the actual files:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\System\GameConfigStore\Children\f198275c-96a8-45b6-a936-a5218456ebe3]
"Type"=dword:00000001
"Revision"=dword:00000517
"Flags"=dword:00000033
"Parent"=hex:01,00,00,00,d0,8c,9d,df,01,15,d1,11,8c,7a,00,c0,4f,c2,97,eb,01,00,\
  00,00,db,b0,ca,53,b8,b8,23,4c,80,98,d7,99,bf,60,50,ce,04,00,00,00,02,00,00,\
  00,00,00,10,66,00,00,00,01,00,00,20,00,00,00,80,ea,2c,6e,63,eb,73,4a,72,b1,\
  77,6d,b5,8d,22,fb,e0,3b,62,3a,e5,22,a8,41,43,e0,df,a3,14,a7,6a,93,00,00,00,\
  00,0e,80,00,00,00,02,00,00,20,00,00,00,f0,cc,de,f3,db,dd,3f,e0,9d,f2,eb,c9,\
  8c,f2,23,88,33,58,de,2a,9b,42,b3,1f,e0,0d,19,ea,00,df,2a,e4,20,00,00,00,5a,\
  7c,32,2e,fc,1a,c3,c3,50,77,77,ae,56,f8,b0,b1,ef,13,8f,23,f0,89,50,7e,cd,12,\
  6c,e1,b2,c4,c4,e6,40,00,00,00,b1,fe,1e,bb,ee,89,16,f2,8e,01,7d,92,ee,46,5e,\
  7e,6e,16,4c,0b,90,8d,58,e3,94,35,c4,4a,8e,32,c8,2c,7b,0d,05,ed,5e,b4,fe,0a,\
  90,47,6e,57,62,be,1e,1f,43,a2,55,a6,da,38,c1,7c,4d,1c,ec,9c,dc,67,65,fc
"GameDVR_GameGUID"="c2f1cd5f-ede9-4e9e-81b1-1c0d96cd1f38"
"TitleId"="1664882211"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\System\GameConfigStore\Parents]

[HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\Software\Fonts]
"LogPixels"=dword:00000060
"LogPixel2s"=dword:00000070

[HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\Software\S] 

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\System\GameConfigStore\Parents\1bc1327236aea4735af068c406dfd7d7b60f8d9c]
"Children"=hex(7):32,00,35,00,62,00,36,00,65,00,62,00,36,00,34,00,2d,00,65,00,\
  30,00,65,00,32,00,2d,00,34,00,65,00,33,00,62,00,2d,00,38,00,32,00,64,00,36,\
  00,2d,00,64,00,65,00,65,00,32,00,32,00,32,00,37,00,62,00,36,00,31,00,64,00,\
  32,00,00,00
```

How can I get the dataframe to read as follows with all paths, keys, types, and values implicitly adding NONE if there are blanks? Example (not inclusive of the dataset due to sizes) below:

```
Path                                 Key                Type       Value
[HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\Software\Fonts] LogPixels          dword      00000060
[HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\Software\Fonts] LogPixel2s         dword      00000070
[HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\Software\S]     None               None       None
```

Comment: Your input are `reg` files or is possible run some powershell script in pc for creating `csv` from `registry` values what can be the easier solution?

Comment: My input is many reg files unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution ended up being much more elegant and faster processesing over multiple hklm files.

```
newlist = []
for section in config.sections():
    for (key, val) in config.items(section):
        newlist.append([section, key, val])

df = pd.DataFrame(newlist)




             Path                    Name                                                                             Data
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ActivatableClasses\Package\EnvironmentsA...        "ActivationType"                                                                   dword:00000000
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ActivatableClasses\Package\EnvironmentsA...                 "CLSID"                                         "{12345665-3CFA-4322-F36F-9880D9BF5604}"
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ActivatableClasses\Package\EnvironmentsA...               "DllPath"  "C:\\Windows\\SystemApps\\EnvironmentsApp_cw5n1h2txyewy\\Analog.Environments...
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ActivatableClasses\Package\EnvironmentsA...             "Threading"                                                                   dword:00000000
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ActivatableClasses\Package\EnvironmentsA...            "TrustLevel"                                                                   dword:00000000
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ActivatableClasses\Package\EnvironmentsA...        "ActivationType"                                                                   dword:00000000
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ActivatableClasses\Package\EnvironmentsA...                 "CLSID"                                         "{123456D5A-343D-89E2-4986-82B497E980F8}"
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ActivatableClasses\Package\EnvironmentsA...               "DllPath"  "C:\\Windows\\SystemApps\\EnvironmentsApp_cw5n1h2zzzzzz\\Analog.Environments...
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ActivatableClasses\Package\EnvironmentsA...             "Threading"                                                                   dword:00000000
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ActivatableClasses\Package\EnvironmentsA...            "TrustLevel"                                                                   dword:00000000
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import re
import io
from configparser import ConfigParser
import pandas as pd


def read_reg(filename, encoding='utf-16'):
    with io.open(filename, encoding=encoding) as f:
        data = f.read()
    # get rid of non-section strings in the beginning of .reg file
    data = re.sub(r'^[^\[]*\n', '', data, flags=re.S)
    cfg = ConfigParser(strict=False)
    # dirty hack for "disabling" case-insensitive keys in "configparser"
    cfg.optionxform=str
    cfg.read_string(data)
    data = []
    # iterate over sections and keys and generate `data` for pandas.DataFrame
    for s in cfg.sections():
        if not cfg[s]:
            data.append([s, None, None, None])
        for key in cfg[s]:
            tp = val = None
            if cfg[s][key]:
                # take care of value type
                if ':' in cfg[s][key]:
                    tp, val = cfg[s][key].split(':')
                else:
                    val = cfg[s][key].replace('"', '').replace(r'\\\n', '')
            data.append([s, key.replace('"', ''), tp, val])
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Path','Key','Type','Value'])
    # make `hex` values "one-line"
    df.loc[df.Type.notnull() & df.Type.str.contains(r'^hex'), 'Value'] = \
        df.loc[df.Type.notnull() & df.Type.str.contains(r'^hex'), 'Value'].str.replace(r'\\\n','')
    return df

filename = '/path/to/regfile.reg'    
# NOTE: you might have to specify the encoding: example: `encoding='utf-8-sig'`, default: 'utf-16' - default for Windows Registry files
df = read_reg(filename)
print(df.loc[df.Path.str.contains(r'Software\\(?:Fonts|S)')])
```

Result:

```
In [236]: print(df.loc[df.Path.str.contains(r'Software\\(?:Fonts|S)')])
                                 Path         Key   Type     Value
7  HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\Software\Fonts   LogPixels  dword  00000060
8  HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\Software\Fonts  LogPixel2s  dword  00000070
9      HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\Software\S        None   None      None
```

Hex values:

```
In [45]: df.loc[df.Type.notnull() & df.Type.str.contains(r'^hex'), 'Value']
Out[45]:
3     01,00,00,00,d0,8c,9d,df,01,15,d1,11,8c,7a,00,c0,4f,c2,97,eb,01,00,00,00,db,b0,ca,53,b8,b8,23,4c,80,98,d7,99,bf,60,50,ce,04,00,00,00,02
,00,00,00,00...
10    32,00,35,00,62,00,36,00,65,00,62,00,36,00,34,00,2d,00,65,00,30,00,65,00,32,00,2d,00,34,00,65,00,33,00,62,00,2d,00,38,00,32,00,64,00,36
,00,2d,00,64...
Name: Value, dtype: object

In [46]: df.loc[df.Type.notnull() & df.Type.str.contains(r'^hex'), 'Value'].str.len()
Out[46]:
3     737
10    221
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

NOTE: i didn't implement any error handling - this might be necessary for production code. So you might want to implement it...

Comment: Not able to check at the moment but does this account for the hex type and put the full set of lines into a single value?

Comment: Had to switch to rawconfigparser to allow for some issues, but overall works as expected. Thanks very much!